# basic memory allocation and free in c

Tags: c, memory-management

Hi I'm new to C programming and have some dificulties with memory allocation

trying to implment a stack using an array

my SP_Stack.c:

```
#include "SP_Stack.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct sp_stack_struct {
      SP_STACK_ELEMENT *elements;
      int top;
};

SP_STACK* spStackCreate(){

    SP_STACK *new_stack = (SP_STACK*)malloc(sizeof(SP_STACK));
    SP_STACK_ELEMENT *newContents = (SP_STACK_ELEMENT*)malloc(sizeof(SP_STACK_ELEMENT)*1024);

    /* make sure to return NULL if needed */
    if( newContents == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    new_stack->elements = newContents;
    new_stack->top = -1;
    return new_stack;
}

void spStackDestroy(SP_STACK* stack){
    //while(!spStackIsEmpty(stack,NULL)){
        //spStackPop(stack,NULL);
//  }
    free(stack->elements);
    free(stack);
}

SP_STACK_ELEMENT* spStackTop (SP_STACK* stack){
    // make sure to return NULL
    if (stack == NULL || spStackIsEmpty(stack)){
        return NULL;
    }
    return &(stack->elements[(stack->top)]);
}
SP_STACK* spStackPop(SP_STACK* stack){

    if (!(stack == NULL || spStackIsEmpty(stack))){
        //free(&(stack->elements[stack->top]));
        //stack->top--;
    }
    return stack;
}
SP_STACK* spStackPush(SP_STACK* stack, SP_STACK_ELEMENT newElement){
    if (stack == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    // copy element so he will stay in memory
    SP_STACK_ELEMENT* copyElement = (SP_STACK_ELEMENT*)malloc(sizeof(SP_STACK_ELEMENT));
    copyElement->type = newElement.type ;
    copyElement->value = newElement.value;

    stack->elements[++stack->top] = *copyElement;
    return stack;
}
bool spStackIsEmpty(SP_STACK* stack){

    return stack->top < 0;
}
```

my SP_Stack.h

```
typedef enum {
    PLUS,
    MINUS,
    MULTIPLICATION,
    DIVISION,
    DOLLAR,
    NUMBER,
    UNKNOWN
} SP_STACK_ELEMENT_TYPE;

typedef struct {
    SP_STACK_ELEMENT_TYPE type;
    double value;
} SP_STACK_ELEMENT;

typedef struct sp_stack_struct SP_STACK;
SP_STACK* spStackCreate();
void spStackDestroy(SP_STACK* stack);
SP_STACK_ELEMENT* spStackTop (SP_STACK* stack);
SP_STACK* spStackPop(SP_STACK* stack);
SP_STACK* spStackPush(SP_STACK* stack, SP_STACK_ELEMENT newElement);
bool spStackIsEmpty(SP_STACK* stack);

#endif /* SP_STACK_H_ */
```

my tester:

```
#include "SP_Stack.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(){
    SP_STACK_ELEMENT* elementPtr = NULL;
    SP_STACK * stack = spStackCreate();
    elementPtr = spStackTop(stack);

    SP_STACK_ELEMENT newElement = {.type = NUMBER , .value = 100};
    SP_STACK_ELEMENT newElement2 = {.type = NUMBER , .value = 200};
    SP_STACK_ELEMENT newElement3 = {.type = NUMBER , .value = 300};
    SP_STACK_ELEMENT newElement4 = {.type = NUMBER , .value = 400};
    SP_STACK_ELEMENT newElement5 = {.type = NUMBER , .value = 500};

    stack = spStackPush(stack,newElement);
    stack = spStackPush(stack,newElement2);
    stack = spStackPush(stack,newElement3);
    stack = spStackPop(stack);

    spStackDestroy(stack);
    return 1;
}
```

my problem is - every time I try to pop an element, my program crashes.

I tried to check my stack->top value is correct an it is.
I also verified it contains an object
by printing the object value in location stack->top

I tried to delete a specific index in my array:

```
free(&(stack->elements[0]));
```

works but, any other index:

```
free(&(stack->elements[1]));
```

crashes, even if elments[i] exits.

what am I doing wrong?
thx

Comment: There's too much missing in your example.  Where is `stack->top` initialized? We need the `SP_STACK_ELEMENT` definition to know if `copyElement->value = newElement.value;' is a valid operation...

Comment: Why do you copy the entire struct by value? `stack->elements[++stack->top] = *copyElement;`

Comment: I have added the code,

Comment: I copy it so it will stay in memory even after the caliing function has finished

Comment: Please! Is it so hard to provide an example that can be compiled? What is `SP_STACK`? What is `SP_STACK_MSG`. Do you have a `main` function for us?

Comment: When you create the stack, you don't assign the created `newContents` to the `elements` field, which stays uninitialised.

Comment: @MOehm added my code here, I also fixed what you said but my code still crashes

Comment: I've seen what your basic error is and have written an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a misconception about how your data is organised in the stack.

You have a dynamic array of entries. This array is created with `malloc` and represented by a pointer, namely the handle to the heap memory.

After you have initialised your stack, that array already contains 1024 uninitialised elements. When you push values, you copy the contents of the array to the top slot. Your code looks like this:

```
SP_STACK_ELEMENT *copyElement =
    (SP_STACK_ELEMENT *) malloc(sizeof(SP_STACK_ELEMENT));

copyElement->type = newElement.type;
copyElement->value = newElement.value;
stack->elements[++stack->top] = *copyElement;
```

You allocate memory, copy the parameters to the copy and then copy the contents of the copy to the array element. The intermediate copy is useless. Worse, the allocated memory is lost, because the handle to `copyElement` immediately.

The code should be just:

```
stack->elements[++stack->top] = *newElement;
```

Conversely, because the memory for the pushed element wasn't really `malloc`ed, you can't `free` it. But because you can't return a pointer to memory that might be overwritten immediately, you can't return the popped element as pointer.

Now you have to make a decision: What do you want to store? Elements or pointers to elements. Storing elements is feasible and easy if your elements are lightweight, for example if they are ints, or doubles. Your struct is lightweight and can be passed around by value. On the other hand, if you store pointers, your client code – the code that uses the stack – must manage the memory.

There are other issues with your code:

- You allocate the stack data proper to a local variable when you initialise the stack, but you never assign it to `stack->elements`.
- Instead of freeing the individual elements, you should free the memory that you have allocated on initialisation. This is best done by a "destructor" or clean-up function.
- Having the `top` index refer to the top element is not C-like and means that you have the index −1 when the stack is empty. I would prefer to make the top member a count, so that en empty stack is represented by a count of zero. That makes checking against over- and underflow easier. It also means that you can use the (unsigned) `size_t` type as index, which is a good choice.

Below is an example that implements a stack as you may have intended it. It stores the elements and passes them around as values. See how, except for the over- and underflow checks, the push and pop functions are very simple.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

enum Type {
    PLUS,
    MINUS,
    NUMBER,
    UNKNOWN
};

typedef struct Stack Stack;
typedef struct Element Element;

struct Element {
    enum Type type;
    double value;
};

struct Stack {
    size_t count;
    Element *elem;
};

#define SP_SIZE 1024

Stack *spStackCreate(void)
{
    Stack *stack = malloc(sizeof(*stack));
    Element *elem = malloc(SP_SIZE * sizeof(*elem));

    if (stack == NULL || elem == NULL) {
        free(stack);
        free(elem);
        return NULL;
    }

    stack->elem = elem;
    stack->count = 0;

    return stack;
}

void spStackDestroy(Stack *stack)
{
    if (stack) {
        free(stack->elem);
        free(stack);
    }
}

void spStackPush(Stack *stack, Element elem)
{
    if (stack->count >= SP_SIZE) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Stack overflow!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    stack->elem[stack->count++] = elem;
}

Element spStackPop(Stack *stack)
{
    if (stack->count == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Stack underflow!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    return stack->elem[--stack->count];
}

int spStackIsEmpty(const Stack *stack)
{
    return (stack->count == 0);
}



int main()
{
    Stack *stack = spStackCreate();
    int i, j = 1;

    if (stack == NULL) exit(1);

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Element elem = {NUMBER, j};

        spStackPush(stack, elem);
        j += i;
    }

    while (!spStackIsEmpty(stack)) {
        Element elem = spStackPop(stack);

        printf("%g\n", elem.value);
    }

    spStackDestroy(stack);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: by doing this : stack->elements[++stack->top] = *newElement;
wont that cause a problem, for example function A creates a stack and calls function B which creates an element and pushes it to the stack, that element wont exists when returning to function A, thats why I tried to copy that element with malloc. In spstacktop, I dont want to return the last element, I want to remove It and also free its memory to avoid memory leaks

Comment: As I said, you create a new element (`copyElement`) that you don't use and discard immediately. Your stack holds an array of elements, not pointers to elements. Therefore the contents of the stack are copies of the elements, much as elements in an array of int are copies of integers.

Comment: You can, of course, create a stack of pointers to elements. In that case, you have to decide whether your stack holds duplicates of the elements or references to elements whose memory is stored elsewhere. (It looks as if you were implementing a calculator, so it's probably the former.) Then your stack requires a field `SP_STACK_ELEMENT **elements`: The top pointer hold the handle to the allocated memory and the second-level pointer holds the copies of duplicated elements. After copying, you should then assign `stack->elements[++stack->top] = newElement`, without the dereferencing asterisk.

Comment: ok I see now. I taught that *elements was an array of pointers.
so to make sure I understand correctly :
elments[1024] is an array of 1024 elments
*elments is a pointer to an array of 1024 elments
**elments is a pointer to an arrray of 1024 pointers to elments?

Comment: If you have a regular array (or array struct member), `Elem elem[1024]`, then `elem` is an array of 1024 elements, `*elem` is the first element and `**elem` doesn't exist. `Elem *elem[1024]` is an array pf 1024 pointers to elements; then `*elem` is the first pointer to element and `**elem` is the element that pointer points to. When you allocate memory dynamically, you get a pointer to the first element of the array. An array of elements would be defined as `Elem *elem` and an array of pointer to elements would be `Elem **elem`.

Comment: Because the first elements of a dynamically allocated array `T *arr` (where `T`is any type) is `*arr`, you can determine the size of such an array with `n * sizeof(*arr)`, where `n` is thze number of elements. This is a very useful pattern for C's low-level memory functions where you must provide a count of bytes, such as `malloc`, `memset` and `memcpy`.

Answer (score 0):

> my problem is - every time I try to pop an element, my program
>   crashes.
>
> I tried to check my stack->top value is correct an it is. I also
>   verified it contains an object by printing the object value in
>   location stack->top
>
> I tried to delete a specific index in my array:
>
> free(&(stack->elements[0])); works but, any other index:
>
> free(&(stack->elements[1])); crashes, even if elments[i] exits.

The first one is working because the `&` operator is taking the address of the first cell in your `stack->elements` array (that address matches the address returned by the `malloc()` call (the one when you initialize the `newContents` variable and so it is a legit address to `free()`.

The second one is getting the address of the second cell in your array, this pointer was not obtained from a `malloc()` call, and as such is very likely to crash when you attempt to `free()` it.

Try removing the `&` operator from `free(&(stack->elements[1]))`, you want to free the actual element, not the cell containing the pointer to the element.